# Iteration error in a function

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have a stream of Observable threads:

```
threads: Observable<{ [key: string]: Thread }>;
```

I want to create a function that iterates every object in my collection to find out if the id given in *threadId* parameter already exists. If it already exists, the function must return *false*.

My function does not work, but I do not know why. She always turns me false :

```
knowNewThread(threadId: string): boolean {
let newThread: boolean = false;
this.threads
  .map((threadDictionary: { [key: string]: Thread }) => {
    for (let key in threadDictionary) {
      if (threadDictionary[key].id === threadId) {
        newThread = true;
      }
    }
  });
return newThread;
}
```

EDIT :

I do not know how to do it. I am inspired by my function which allows me to return the *thread* according to the *threadId* given parameter:

```
getThreadFromSubscription(threadId: string): Observable<Thread> {
return this.threads
  .filter((threadDictionary: { [key: string]: Thread }) => {
    return Object.keys(threadDictionary).some((key) =>
      threadDictionary[key].id === threadId);
  })
  .map((threadDictionary: { [key: string]: Thread }) => {
    for (let key in threadDictionary) {
      if (threadDictionary[key].id === threadId)
      {
        return threadDictionary[key];
      }
    }
  }).first();
}
```

And after to subscribe I do this :

```
this.getThreadFromSubscription(objMessage.id)
    .subscribe ((thread: Thread) => {
      objMessage.thread = thread;
});
```

Should I be inspired to create my function or is it different?

Initializing my *thread* variable in *threadService* :

```
this.threads = messageService.messages
  .map((messages: Message[]) => {
    const threads: { [key: string]: Thread } = {};
    messages.map((message: Message) => {
      threads[message.thread.id] = threads[message.thread.id] ||
        message.thread;

      const messagesThread: Thread = threads[message.thread.id];
      if (!messagesThread.lastMessage ||
        messagesThread.lastMessage.date < message.date) {
        messagesThread.lastMessage = message;
      }
    });
    return threads;
  });
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

EDIT

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

When I subscribe to my knowNewThread function, it returns a list of boolean variables.
Outside I would like that when I scoucirs to this function, it returns a single boolean variable true or false.

Here is what I wrote:

```
knowNewThread(threadId: string): Observable<boolean> {
return this.threads
  .map((threadDictionary: { [key: string]: Thread }) => {
    let newThread: boolean = false;
    for (let key in threadDictionary) {
      if (threadDictionary[key].id === threadId) {
        newThread = true;
      }
    }
    return newThread;
  }).first();
}

newThread: boolean = false;

this.knowNewThread(objMessage.id)
  .subscribe( (test: boolean) => {
    if(test === true) {
      this.newThread = true;
    }
});
```

When the id is already known, I would like to have my variable newThread to false, conversely for an unknown id, I would like the variable newThread to be true.

Comment: You seem to think of Observable as a collection, or a box containing something. That's not, at all, what it is. An Observable is more like a phone. You turn on the phone (i.e. subscribe to the observable), indicating that you would like to receive phone calls (i.e. events). And some time, later, you receive phone calls (i.e. events). You can't just open the phone and see all the phone calls waiting for you. Sorry, but that's all I can say. You really need to understand what an Observable is about, because what you're trying to do doesn't make sense.

Comment: @JBNizet
I really do not know how to go about it. I edited my post by adding details

Comment: I can't answer. Not without knowing why you're using observables in the first place, what these methods are for, where they're being used, etc. The general way of dealing with observables is to get them from services, subscribe to them in components and store the event they emit in the component, and to work with the data in the component (not with observables). So, if you need to display threads, store the threads in your component (not the Observable) and deal with the threads.

Comment: @JBNizet
My thread variable is initailized in a threadService service
I then search through these threads to see if the id is already in use or not. I reedited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```ts
knowNewThread(threadId: string): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.threads
  .map((threadDictionary: { [key: string]: Thread }) => {
    let newThread: boolean = false;
    for (let key in threadDictionary) {
      if (threadDictionary[key].id === threadId) {
        newThread = true;
      }
    }
    return newThread;
  });
}
```

In your code

```ts
return newThread;
```

will be executed before

```ts
for (let key in threadDictionary) { ...
```

because an Observable is async.

Comment: Its important to note that you will need to subscribe to this since the return will now be of type Observable<boolean> instead of boolean

Comment: @LLai
How can I do next to just had a variable true or false?
I did this but I get full of boolean values : this.knowNewThread(objMessage.id).subscribe( (test: boolean) => {
this.newThread = test});

Comment: @Floriane sorry, but I can't make sense of your comment. What does the data look like? What is the expected result?

Comment: Sorry I'm not very clear. I published my post hoping that you will understand better

Comment: @Floriane as mentioned in one of the other comments, you need to start from the beginning. Why are you using an observable, when you only want a single value? Where do the values the observable emits come from? With about code, you'll get a single boolean value for each value emitted by the observable.

Comment: I want a unique value at the end of my _knowNewThread_ function.
I want to know if the_id_ is known to determine if the message I add is part of an existing conversation or if I need to create a new conversation to add it.